# Facebook iOS SDK Poke

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to "poke" a Facebook friend using the Facebook SDK for iOS? I've toyed around with the online API explorer and sifted through the documentation, but couldn't find a public API.

Does anyone know of a Graph API request that I can make to poke a Facebook friend through my iOS app?

Comment: I dont think there is any api for Poke...

Comment: Doing a bit more research...it looks like the API has been whitelisted by FB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, It is not possible to poke a Facebook friend through the graph API or SDK for iOS. I am also looking for this functionality for my App.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a public Poke API in the Facebook SDK yet.