# how to poke a facebook friend using ios 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook iOS SDK Poke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005689/facebook-ios-sdk-poke)

I want to poke a facebook friend using ios 6.

I am using social media framework.

please suggest me if there is any way to poke a friend.

Comment: Your question is more relative to [Facebook Api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) than ios. So suggesting searching there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to poke someone through the API. Sorry.

And Im thankful for that...

Comment: ok

thanx for your reply.

is there any way to send private message through api ? 

and are you 100% sure that there is no api to poke a friend ?

Comment: @user1003179 Yeah dude, 100 percent sure. Sending messages through the API **was** possible, not anymore though. You can however send a request to friends (to use your app). If this helped, upvote and tick (green tick silhouette)